# Docker Cannot Run CURL or WGET Commands To Localhost

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose

I have an issue I discovered while trying to try **PHPUnit** tests with CURL commands. I always get:

```
Connecting to `www.example.local` (www.example.local)|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

I then tried to run **wget** and **curl** commands from the container **command line**, same problem. I have docker working like this.

In my computer’s /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.local
127.0.0.1 api.example.local
```

and so forth and it works when accessing the sites in my browser. In my docker-compse.yml, I have:

```
version: “3.4”

volumes:
  postgres_database :
     external: false
  mysql_data : {}
  schemas:
    external: false
services:
  php:
    build:
      context : ./
      dockerfile : Dockerfile
      network: host
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    depends_on: [ "postgres"]

    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    expose:
      - "9000"
    container_name: binge_php
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    build:
      context : ./
      dockerfile : Dockerfile_Nginx
      network: host
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - "0"
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
      - ./nginx_custom_settings.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx_custom_settings.conf

    links:
      - php
    depends_on:
      - php
    container_name: binge_nginx
```

What might I be doing wrong that is preventing me from running curl commands from inside the PHP container?

Comment: In Docker 127.0.0.1 generally means "this container", not any other container or the host system.

Comment: @DavidMaze but if my network is `network: host`, shouldn't it be the same as my host system?

Comment: host network does mean that you can access any other container using `localhost`, localhost mean this container, to access other container you have to use the container name, but I am wander it may not work in host network, as Note: Given that the container does not have its own IP-address when using host mode networking, port-mapping does not take effect, and the -p, --publish, -P, and --publish-all option are ignored, producing a warning instead:

WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

Comment: You're only building containers using the host network, not running them.  That's usually an unnecessary workaround, though, and you shouldn't need to specify it at all.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The compose file provided includes lots of references to external files not included in the question.